# Cant figure out XMLNamespace in my Linq to XML query

Tags: c#, web-services, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

Format of XML from webservice:

```
<Data xmlns="http://www.mywebservice.com/schema/data">
  <Record>
       <PCI>
            <FNAME>Random</FNAME>
            <LNAME>Guy</LNAME>
            <BIO />
       </PCI>
  </Record>
</Data>
```

My Linq-to-XML query:

```
XNamespace xns = "http://www.mywebservice.com/schema/data";
var Records = from Record in userInfo.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "Record")
        select new
        {
           fname = Record.Element(xns + "FNAME").Value,
        };
```

This query fails. When in debug mode i click Records, then Results View to see if it contains anything. It just gives me a Object Reference not set to instance of object

if I do this:

```
select new
{
    Record,
}
```

all just returns all of the xml, so I know the Descendants method is correctly reading the xml

I've searched for answers but I cant find out whats going on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're looking for `FNAME` using `Element`, when it's an element of `PCI`, not of `Record`.  Either use `Descendant` or find it as an `Element` of `PCI`.

Also, it looks like both `userinfoNamespace` and `xns` must be `"http://www.mywebservice.com/schema/data"` for it to work right.  You might only need one of those variables.

Comment: yeah sorry they are the same, just some renaming stuff. But you mean like Record.Element(xns +"PCI").Element(xns+"FNAME").Value?

Comment: var Records = from Record in userInfo.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "Record")
            select new
            {
               ophone1 = Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace +                              "OPHONE1").Single().Value,
               ophone2 = Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "OPHONE2").Single().Value,
               ophone3 = Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "OPHONE3").Single().Value,
                                              };